# How was Mary fighting human forces?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist-2017

Mary Walker apparently was present at

> the Battle of Sokovia,

where (apparently) she experienced the trauma that caused her DID. The show talks as if she was in a battle with human (or at least flesh and blood) Sokovian soldiers.

> WALKER:These Sokovians, they like knives.

She also seems to be covered in blood (not her own), when she is discovered.

However, we know that the Battle of Sokovia consisted of *robots* against the Avengers and some allies.  If the forces of Sokovia weren't fleeing, they were also fighting Ultron's robotic army.

How, precisely, was she fighting human, Sokovian soldiers?

Comment: We don't know when that was, it could have been before the events of Age of Ultron, during, or after. It is easy to imagine a destabilized Sokovia after the events of AoU, where the US might intervene to try and bring peace back to the region.

Comment: Indeed, Iron Fist does *not* specifically reference the Battle of Sokovia AFAIK.